# Octopress, github pages, CNAME domain and google website search

Tags: github, google-search, octopress

My [blog](http://www.convalesco.org) was successfully transferred to [octopress](http://octopress.org) and github-pages. My problem though is that website's search uses [google search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=test&q=site%3awww.convalesco.org) but the result of 'search' as you can see, are pointing to the old (wordpress) links. Now these links have change structure, following default octopress structure.

I don't understand why this is happening. Is it possible for google to have stored in it's DB the old links (my blog was 1st page for some searches, but gathered just 3.000 hits / month... not much by internet's standards) and this will change with time, or is it something I'm able to change somehow?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.You can wait for Google to crawl and re-index your 
pages, or you can use the URL Removal Request tool 
to expedite removal of old pages from the index. 
http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=61062
According to that page, the removal process 
"usually takes 3-5 business days."

Consider submitting a Sitemap: 
http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=40318
[click here](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url) to resubmit your sitemap.

More information about Sitemaps:
http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=34575 
http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/topic.py?topic=8467 
http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/topic.py?topic=8477 
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/docs/en/protocol.html

2.Perhaps your company might consider the 
Google Mini?  You could set up the Mini to 
crawl the site every night or even 'continuously'.

http://www.google.com/enterprise/mini/

According to the US pricing page, 
the Mini currently starts at $1995 for a 
50,000-document license with a year of support.

Here is the Google Mini discussion group: 
http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Mini 
 http://www.google.com/enterprise/hosted_vs_appliance.html 
 (Click: "show all descriptions") 
 http://www.google.com/support/mini/ 
 (Google Mini detailed FAQ)

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-custom-search-creating-and-editing/-4jRF057O_w by omr

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. I'll try to do all of these things and see what goes! Thanks!

Comment: Apparently that didn't work. I did remove my page for google. And was removed entirely. Then I added the page back with a sitemap, but still the links that google displays are the wrong ones. I might need to wait until google's cache is fully update (which apparently will take too much time). I don't think that I can do anything else.

Comment: Hello, I actually removed xCode - that was one big mess on Mountain Lion - macports and re-installed everything. Worked fine now!

Also thanks for the the great RVM software! :-)

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your message, re-installed is a good idea. :>